# Sound strategy for extending Django User model?

Tags: django, django-registration

This seems like it should be fine, since I'm not touching the User model itself.

I want to register users purely based on email and password.  Username is required in the User model.  My thought is that I can just create a custom UserCreationForm that saves email address AS username and validates the email address.

Unfortunately, with that, I'll have to refer to email address via user.username going forward.

Is this standard? Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Don't do that: you will run into problems when email length gets too long for the default user field. You could do that if you look into some other SO posts about extending the length of the username field. I've resorted to storing a hash of email address as username and log in users via email address.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that username had a limit of 30 characters, how annoying.  Your method makes sense Yuji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My thought is that I can just create a custom UserCreationForm that saves email address AS username and validates the email address.

Close.

Use the `clean` method to copy email address to username.  This works out pretty well for everything but the default login form.

The default login form needs to be tweaked to allow username to be an email address.  The default form expects characters only, and rejects punctuation.

Comment: ah ha, this seems nice and simple.  Thanks Lott

Answer (score 2):

Some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896421/how-to-change-default-django-user-model-to-fit-my-needs).

Seems like the best method may be to write a [custom auth backend](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend) (not too  difficult) to accept email addresses to log in, and store a hash of the email in the username field to satisfy the required, unique username.

Comment: If Lott's method doesn't work, I'd certainly try this.  thank dgel